# Populate text field based on result of dropdown selection

Tags: jquery

Using MVC 5, I have created a dropdown menu with three options: $500, $5000 and Other. I want to hide the "AmountOther" text field until the user has selected the "AmountOther" Option from the dropdown. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <div class="col-md-10" id="divAmount"> 
      <select class="form-control" data-val="true" id="Amount" name="Amount">
      <option value="">-- Amount --</option>
      <option value="500">$500</option>
      <option value="5000">$5000</option>
      <option value="AmountOther">Amount Other</option>
     </select>
   <div>

   <div class="col-md-10" id="divAmount"> 
     <input id="AmountOther" name="AmountOther" type="text" value="" />
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
 $('#Amount').live('change',function() {
    if (value == "AmountOther") {
        $("#divAmount").show();
        $("#divAmount").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#divAmount").hide();
        $("#divAmount").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comments, IDs must be unique. Also, since jQuery 1.7 `.on()` is preferred to `.live()` which has been deprecated. With that, you can use:

```
$('#Amount').on('change', function () {
    $('#divAmount2').css('display', ($(this).val() == 'AmountOther') ? 'block' : 'none')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/37qj4c1c/)**

```js
$('#Amount').on('change', function() {
  $('#divAmount2').css('display', ($(this).val() == 'AmountOther') ? 'block' : 'none')
});
```

```css
#divAmount2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10" id="divAmount">
  <select class="form-control" data-val="true" id="Amount" name="Amount">
    <option value="">-- Amount --</option>
    <option value="500">$500</option>
    <option value="5000">$5000</option>
    <option value="AmountOther">Amount Other</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-10" id="divAmount2">
      <input id="AmountOther" name="AmountOther" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't get this thing to work. I even created a simple html file and copy and paste the code above and still no luck. I am using 'jquery-2.1.3.js' can this be the issue?

Comment: It should still work with that version. Are you getting errors in the console? Are you loading the jQuery at the end of the document or within a document ready handler?

Answer (score 0):

`value` is undefined in that context. You also have duplicated ID's. `live` is now `on`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
 $('#Amount').on('change',function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('Amount');
    if (elem.value == "AmountOther") {
        $("#divAmount").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#divAmount").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Amount').live('change',function() {
    if($('#Amount:selected').text() == 'Amount Other'){
       $("#divAmount").show();
    }else{
       $("#divAmount").hide();
    }
});
```